# Parenting a null causes unexpected results

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I've built an arrow that is controlled by two nulls - one at the start point and one at the end point.  Using some trigonometry in some expressions, it works.  When I move the nulls, the arrow resizes appropriately.

But when I try to parent one of the nulls to another object (like another null, or a shape layer), the null position jumps.  And even after parenting, the parent null can't move the child null.. Any ideas?

video:

Below are snippets of the controlling code, based on some [scripts by others](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/227/6984) that I found online.

arrowlength controlled by

```
CellTower = thisComp.layer("startpoint").transform.position;
Target = thisComp.layer("endpoint").transform.position;
sizefactor = 100/(effect("ArrowSize")("Slider"));
BeamLength = (length(CellTower, Target)*sizefactor)-150;
[BeamLength]
```

rotation of the arrow controlled by

```
CellTower=thisComp.layer("startpoint").transform.position;
Target=thisComp.layer("endpoint").transform.position;

// Find the length of side a
SideA = sub(CellTower, Target)[1];

// Find the length of side b
SideB = sub(CellTower, Target)[0];

//Find the Angle between them
-1*(270-(radiansToDegrees(Math.atan2(SideA, SideB))+180));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem there is that the expression is using the position value for the null. As you know when you parent a layer to another layer its position becomes relative to its parent. So if for example you have a null at [960,540] and you parent it to a layer whose position is also [960,540] the null's position now becomes [0,0]. This means that any expressions that use that value now are seeing [0,0] instead of [960,540].

So you need to feed the null's absolute position in world space to the expression. This is where the mysterious **Layer Space Transform** functions come into play.

Change the parts of the expression that have the null's position from

```
CellTower=thisComp.layer("startpoint").transform.position;
```

to

```
startPoint = thisComp.layer("startpoint"); 
//use a variable just to make the next line easier to understand
CellTower=startPoint.toWorld(startPoint.anchorPoint);
```

What that is doing is translating a point as seen from the relative coordinates of the layer startPoint to the world coordinates of the comp. The point that we're giving it to translate is startPoint's anchor point.